# Add all elements from object to FormData object - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to append all elements in an object dynamically to a `FormData` object. How is this possible?

I don't want to append everything manually.

```
var myFd = new FormData();
myFd.append('user', dataObj.user);
myFd.append('image', dataObj.image);
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `for` loop:

```
var myObject = {
    'prop1': 'value1',
    'prop2': 'value2'
};

var myFd = new FormData();

for(var propertyName in myObject) {
    if(myFd.hasOwnProperty(propertyName) == false) {
        myFd.append(propertyName, myObject[propertyName]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you stranger! WebStorm gives me this warning: 'Possible iteration over unexpected (custom / inherited) members, probably missing hasOwnProperty check'. Do I need to be concerned about this?

Comment: @user3475602 No, you don't need to be concerned. It's warning you about private properties.

Comment: Just add a `hasOwnProperty` check.

Comment: @user3475602 As @SalmanA said, check with `hasOwnProperty` if object, to which You appending properites, had those properies earlier. If yes, just don't append them (or do sth else, for example, change name of property).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for in` loop:

```
var myFd = new FormData();

for(var key in dataObj)
{
    myFd.append(key, dataObj[key]);
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9psbeff0/)